# Azure AD authentication via Powershell returns null

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm trying to authenticate to my Intune tenant using Powershell & the AzureAD module.  In Windows Powershell (5.1) it works, but in Powershell 7 the same code returns null.  I get the login prompt, enter my credentials, and respond to the MFA prompt on my phone.  Any ideas on what's happening?

```bsh
$Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$ClientID = "d1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547"
$RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
# $PlatformParams has PromptBehavior set to Always
$Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$AuthenticationContext = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $Authority -ErrorAction Stop

$AuthenticationResult = ($AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync($Resource, $ClientID, $RedirectUri, $PlatformParams)).Result
```

$AuthenticationResult is null in Powershell 7, but contains the expected data in Powershell 5.1.

Comment: Is this `$Resource = "https:///graph.microsoft.com"` just a typo when you've posted the question here? There are three forward slashes.

Comment: Try installing AadSupport using `Install-Module -Name AadSupport` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, the /// was a typo here only.  It's correct in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 6/7 (aka cross-platform core) encourages you to use new Az modules based on [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest). For AAD, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest) and [get access token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token).

If you still insist to use the legacy AzureAD module for some reason, consider running in compatibility mode (though I don't see reason to stick to the legacy once since you already seem to got into the new powershell). People have written [blog post](https://endjin.com/blog/2019/05/how-to-use-the-azuread-module-in-powershell-core) about that (Disclaimer: Haven't tried myself).

Also in your example code, I see you are anyway not using any powershell cmdlet, but [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) objects. That is another thing I recommend you to avoid (though not directly related to this problem). ADAL is deprecated and replaced by [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet). Powershell module [MSAL.PS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS).

Example using MSAL.PS:

```
Install-Module -Name MSAL.PS
Get-MsalToken -ClientId 'd1ddf0e4-d672-4dae-b554-9d5bdfd93547' -TenantId 'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com' -Scopes 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  The code I'm troubleshooting was written by someone else, so I'll look at incorporating you suggestions.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I included MSAL example.